# Can we tweet something from website to timeline in twitter without calling twitter box platform?

Tags: php, javascript, twitter

My website is allow user to tweet something to their timeline in twitter. When they click on tweet button, twitter box platform will popup and user can write or edit something before tweet; but i don't want this way, i want is when they click on tweet button it will tweet to their timeline automatically (no need to call twitter box platform). Does it is possible to do like this?

**My code**

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" id="'.$id.'" 
data-text="'.$tweet.'" data-lang="ja" data-size="large" data-count="none" 
data-url="none">Tweet</a>

<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;
js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs); 
}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tmhOAuth I believe. Even though it still goes through the twitter servers, you don't call the twitter box platform. Google "tmhOAuth" if you've never heard of it.

Comment: Okay, i will check for this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sorry folks but that's not available, because to twitter the one has to login on twitter and obviously the twitter box should open to check and after that we can't control what twitter does. So Simply this is not possible